# readline tries to be intelligent on completion. how to disable?

Tags: python, readline

I was inserting `"` and pressed tab. I expected to get `text == "\""` in my completer function. But I got the empty string. Similarly, when I enter `a,` or so, I also just get the empty string in my completer function.

How can I disable this behavior?

---

Sample code:

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind('tab: complete')
def completer(text, state):
    return []
readline.set_completer(completer)
```

Comment: can you put some part of code or anything that you tried?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh: I don't quite see how that adds anything because I don't do anything at all. But there you have it.

Comment: Am I the only one who doesn't get the question?

Comment: @Johnny: What exactly aren't you getting? With the sample code, when you are in `raw_input` and you insert `"` and then press tab, readline will call `completer`. And inside that function, you have `text == ""`. But I expected to have `text == "\""`. And I want to have that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what I want:

```
readline.set_completer_delims("")
```